# Examples of noncontinuous functions that are continuous intuitively

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can someone provide examples of noncontinuous functions that seem continuous? I want to explain limits to a friend, but I can't think of an example that's noncontinuous (which isn't "obviously" discontinuous, like functions of the form $f(x)/(x-c)$, pathological functions, or piecewise functions). I also know only basic analysis.

They've only learned the numerical method to "test" if a function is continuous, which is plugging in points close to the suspicious point. I'm hesitant (but willing if necessary) to introduce the epsilon-delta definition, but I also can't think of any examples even with this definition. I also don't want to use something like the Dirichlet indicator function because they don't know the relationship between rational and real numbers, so they may not appreciate/understand that it's continuous on the rationals but not on the reals.

In particular, the student is asking about functions that aren't "deliberately" constructed to be noncontinuous (because piecewise functions usually reveal where the discontinuities might take place).

To clarify, the most important property is that the function’s discontinuities don’t have a one-to-one correspondence to the zeroes of the denominators of its fractions. If a zero in a denominator  produces more than one discontinuity, then this would be an example I would be interested in.

Another detail I want is that if the function is piecewise, then that all its discontinuities aren’t at the points where the function’s pieces are redefined.

Comment: How about the derivative of $x^2\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Why do not you try step function?

Comment: @imtrying46 That function is certainly not defined at x = 0, but I'll see if it's continuous everywhere else, which is what I currently expect.

Comment: @dmtri I can choose epsilon = 0.5, and it also looks discontinuous (when there is no vertical line drawn to connect the step).

Comment: @SamuelHan it most certainly is! Let $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, which a priori is only defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. But we may extend $f$ continuously to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(0):=0$. Then, we have $f'(0):=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/x$, and this limit exists and is equal to $0$. Certainly the derivative also exists at non-zero values, and it is then a nice exercise to show that $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$, but continuous everywhere else.

Comment: Neither of the comments adress the question. I think it won't be easy to find such an example. A step function has a trivial discontinuity and is definitely not what is desired.

Comment: @Peter Why doesn't the derivative of $x^2\sin(1/x)$ address the question? To me it isn't at all obvious why it should be discontinuous, and when learning analysis I think it is rather surprising that even when the derivative exists everywhere, said derivative can be discontinuous.

Comment: @imtrying46 The function $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ is continuous on its domain; I wouldn't call it discontinuous at all. Even if you extend it to $f(0) = 0$, then you get something that's sort of the opposite: seemingly discontinuous (as $1/x$ blows up), but is actually continuous. Its derivative *sort of* fits the bill: it's definitely discontinuous, but one might intuitively believe that all derivatives are continuous, but that impression wouldn't survive writing out the derivative explicitly as a piecewise function.

Comment: My own suggestion, which isn't much better, would be $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$. When looking at this map naively, the map is plagued with problems, though most of which are to do with definitions. You could look at, say, $0^x$ (naively defined as $0$) as $x \to 0$ compared with $x^x$ as $x \to 0$. Because exponentiation is perceived as a "basic" operation, most of which are continuous most of the time, the discontinuities could be somewhat unexpected to a naive learner.

Comment: @TheoBendit I never called $x^2\sin(1/x)$ discontinuous, I was always referring to its derivative.

Comment: @imtrying46 Ah, I see that now. My apologies. I do still have reservations about it though.

Comment: how about $x/\sqrt{(x^2)}$

Comment: On thing to keep in mind is that you might have a tough time finding a discontinuous function without "graphically obvious discontinuities", since the "draw without lifting your hand up" definition of continuity can actually be made into a precise definition that really is accurate, namely, $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if the graph of $f$ is path-connected.  (Can replace the target with any Hausdorff space actually - maybe even a general topological space, but the proof wasn't obvious to me without Hausdorff)

Comment: @MW Thank you; I didn’t know that a real function was continuous iff its graph was path-connected. I’ll edit my question to account for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the suggestion of @imtrying46 is a good one. It is known that [derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), a property which at first glance looks like it is only satisfied by continuous functions, so it might be surprising that the function is not continuous.

But here is another suggestion. Consider the function given by $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$t \mapsto\sup_N \Bigg [ \tanh \bigg(\sum_{2 \le n \le N} \frac{1}{(n \ln^2 n )^t} \bigg) \Bigg] $$

inspired by the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292972/union-of-lp-0p1/3292999#3292999). Note that the $\tanh$ is only needed so that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, and the $\sup$ is only needed to avoid having to write this as a piecewise function. But it's not too difficult to think about the behaviour of this function intuitively (e.g. it is clearly decreasing), and I think that most people would expect this function to be continuous.

However, it turns out that:

$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
0.971 \text{ (approx.)}, & \text{if t = 1}\\
1, & \text{if t < 1}
\end{cases}
$$

In other words, there is a jump discontinuity at $t = 1$, due to the fact that:

$$\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{1}{(n \ln^2 n )^t} < \infty \text{ if and only if } t \ge 1$$

This is a result which feels quite surprising to me. I think that it is natural to expect that convergence at some value $t$ would imply convergence in an open neighbourhood of $t$.